# Can I use Homebrew on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, homebrew, linuxbrew

I just tried to use Homebrew and Linuxbrew to install packages on my Ubuntu Server but both failed. This is how I tried to install them:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential curl git m4 ruby texinfo libbz2-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libexpat-dev libncurses-dev zlib1g-dev

ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew/go/install)"
```

I got the following warning:

```
Warning: /home/tong/.linuxbrew/bin is not in your PATH.
```

I vi my bash.bashrc in home/etc and add this:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
```

Then I tried `brew doctor` but got `No command 'brew' found`. How am I able to use Homebrew on Ubuntu?

Comment: Excuse me, now I have a zinc-0.3.9.tgz, and I want to install this zinc compile server, what apt command should I use? apt-get install can not locate the package and I have to download the tgz first and then install it locally. Thanks

Comment: Not sure what "my bash.bashrc in home/etc" means but .bash_profile and .bashrc are expected to be in $HOME.

Comment: `snapcraft.io` might be worth checking out

Comment: here is the answer from the doc if someone is still looking
https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I just tried installing it using the ruby command but somehow the dependencies are not resolved hence brew does not completely install. But, try installing by cloning:

```
git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew.git ~/.linuxbrew
```

and then add the following to your `.bash_profile`:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
```

It should work..

Comment: You mean I can install it just by clone it?

Comment: For cloning you need to first clean/remove the .linuxbrew that was created under your user space. Then effectively you need to execute git clone which would get the package and then include the export commands to your bash_profile file.

Comment: Yes it does. I just did a fresh install. What kind of error are you facing?

Comment: I'm not sure. what is the .bash_profile file. Do you vi it as a new file or does it locate somewhere else?

Comment: And my .linuxbrew locate in $home/tong/.linuxbrew do i need to change the export path  you gave me?

Comment: Run the following commands in sequence : `1) rm -rf $home/tong/.linuxbrew`   2) `git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew.git ~/.linuxbrew`  3) go to your home  and create .bash_profile using vi  4) paste the export commands into this file  5) After that open a new terminal window and then type in brew to see if it works

Comment: from https://docs.brew.sh/Linuxbrew, you can now use `sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/install/master/install.sh)"`, then add `eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)` to your `~/.zshrc` or `~/.profile`, this will add Linuxbrew to your `PATH`

Answer (score 54):

**Update:**

Seems like the package is no more maintained. I'd suggest [go with solution provided by Lars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33354198/147407).

**Old answer:**

As of February 2018, installing `brew` on Ubuntu (mine is 17.10) machine is as simple as:

```
sudo apt install linuxbrew-wrapper
```

Then, on first `brew` execution (just type `brew --help`) you will be asked for two installation options:

```
me@computer:~/$ brew --help
==> Select the Linuxbrew installation directory
- Enter your password to install to /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew (recommended)
- Press Control-D to install to /home/me/.linuxbrew
- Press Control-C to cancel installation
[sudo] password for me:
```

For recommended option type your password (if your current user is in `sudo` group), or, if you prefer installing all the dependencies in your own home folder, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Enjoy.

Comment: Why is  /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew recommended?

Comment: Obviously, for security reasons. `brew` will run then under its dedicated user. Think of `apache` and `www-data`, as an example.

Comment: Thanks. But I am unaware of `apache` and `www-data`. Also, what are the security concerns, given that it does not require sudo rights?

Comment: That's quite a big topic, which I'm pretty sure is covered on https://serverfault.com. I'd say, if your machine is not exposed to internet, but a development machine or similar, you probably should not care.

Comment: I get this error ```E: Unable to locate package linuxbrew-wrapper
```

Answer (score 18):

as of august 2020 (works for kali linux as well)

```
sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Linuxbrew/install/master/install.sh)"

export brew=/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin

test -d ~/.linuxbrew && eval $(~/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)

test -d /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew && eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)

test -r ~/.profile && echo "eval \$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)" >>~/.profile     // for ubuntu and debian
```

Comment: this is definitely the way to install homebrew on linux now.

Comment: if anyone running .zsh shell, run all and replace the last line with this -- `test -r ~/.zshrc && echo "eval \$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)" >>~/.zshrc`

Comment: Warning: Linuxbrew has been merged into Homebrew.
Please migrate to the following command:
  `/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"`

Answer (score 15):

The following steps worked for me:

- Clone it from github

  ```
  git clone https://github.com/Homebrew/linuxbrew.git ~/.linuxbrew
  ```
- Open your .bash_profile file using `vi ~/.bash_profile`
- Add these lines

  ```
  export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
  export MANPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/man:$MANPATH"
  export INFOPATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/share/info:$INFOPATH"
  ```
- Then type the following lines in your terminal

  ```
  export PATH=$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH
  hash -r
  ```

Yes, it is done. Type `brew` in your terminal to check its existence.

Comment: It seems that my binaries are installed to `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/opt/**/*/bin`

Answer (score 7):

You can just follow instructions from the [Homebrew on Linux docs](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux), but I think it is better to understand what the instructions are trying to achieve.

#### Understanding the installation steps can save some time

**Step 1: Choose location**

First of all, it is important to understand that *linuxbrew* will be installed on the `/home` directory and not inside `/home/your-user` (the `~` directory). 
(See the reason for that at the end of answer).
Keep this in mind when you run the other steps below.

**Step 2: Add *linuxbrew* binaries to `/home`** :

The [installation script](https://brew.sh/) will do it for us:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
```

**Step 3: Check that `/linuxbrew` was added to the relevant location**

This can be done by simply navigating to `/home`.
Notice that the [docs](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux) are showing it as a one-liner by adding `test -d <linuxbrew location>` before each command.

(Read more about the `test` command in [here](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Test_command)).

**Step 4: Export relevant environment variables to terminal**

We need to add *linuxbrew* to `PATH` and add some more environment variables to the current terminal.

We can just add the following `export`s to terminal (wait don't do it..):

```
export PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin${PATH+:$PATH}";

export HOMEBREW_PREFIX="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew";
export HOMEBREW_CELLAR="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Cellar";
export HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew";
export MANPATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/man${MANPATH+:$MANPATH}:";
export INFOPATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/share/info:${INFOPATH:-}";
```

Or simply run (If your *linuxbrew* folder is on other location then  `/home` - change the path):

```
eval $(/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv)
```

(*) Because `brew` command is not yet identified by the current terminal (this is what we're solving right now) we'll have to specify the full path to the brew binary: `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/brew shellenv`

Test this step by:

1 ) Run `brew` from current terminal to see if it identifies the command.

2 ) Run `printenv` and check if all environment variables were exported and that you see `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin` on `PATH`.

**Step 5: Ensure step 4 is running on each terminal**

We need to add step 4 to `~/.profile` (in case of Debian/Ubuntu):

```
echo "eval \$($(brew --prefix)/bin/brew shellenv)" >> ~/.profile
```

For CentOS/Fedora/Red Hat - replace `~/.profile` with `~/.bash_profile`.

**Step 6: Ensure that `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` are being executed when new terminal is opened**

If you executed step 5 and failed to run `brew` from new terminal - add a test command like `echo "Hi!"` to `~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile`. 
If you don't see `Hi!` when you open a new terminal - go to the terminal preferences and ensure that the attribute of '*run command as login shell*' is set. 
Read more in [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/566399/why-isnt-profile-sourced-when-opening-a-terminal).

---

Why the installation script installs Homebrew to `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew` - from [here](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux#install):

> The installation script installs Homebrew to
> `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew` using `sudo` if possible and in your home
> directory at `~/.linuxbrew` otherwise. Homebrew does not use `sudo`
> after installation. 
>  Using `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew` allows the
> use of more binary packages (bottles) than installing in your personal
> home directory.
>
> The prefix `/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew` was chosen so that users
> without admin access can ask an admin to create a *linuxbrew* role
> account and still benefit from precompiled binaries.
>
> If you do not yourself have admin privileges, consider asking your
> admin staff to create a *linuxbrew* role account for you with home
> directory `/home/linuxbrew`.

Answer (score 3):

Linux is now officially supported in brew - see the [Homebrew 2.0.0](https://brew.sh/2019/02/02/homebrew-2.0.0/) blog post. As shown on https://brew.sh, just copy/paste this into a command prompt:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Because all previous answers doesn't work for me for ubuntu 14.04
here what I did, if any one get the same problem:

```
git clone https://github.com/Linuxbrew/brew.git ~/.linuxbrew
PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
export MANPATH="$(brew --prefix)/share/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="$(brew --prefix)/share/info:$INFOPATH"
```

then

```
sudo apt-get install gawk
sudo yum install gawk
brew install hello
```

you can follow this [link](http://linuxbrew.sh/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

October 2019 - Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL with oh-my-zsh;
the [instructions](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux) here worked perfectly -

(first, install pre-requisites using  **sudo apt-get install build-essential curl file git**)

finally create a **`~/.zprofile`** with the following contents:
**`emulate sh -c '. ~/.profile'`**

Answer (score 1):

Whta to do

```
   cd /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin
    ./brew doctor
```

You will get what path to export

```
   echo 'export PATH="/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```