# Command 'brew' not found after installing Laravel

Tags: laravel, bash, homebrew

I am in my Ubuntu server using terminal with a super user. I installed brew with `sudo apt install linuxbrew-wrapper`. I tried the command `brew search mysql`, and it comes back with the response:

> Command 'brew' not found, but can be installed with:
>
> sudo apt install linuxbrew-wrapper

I looked up [this issue](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148901/why-does-my-brew-installation-not-work) and it suggests to run the command for your path environment variable `echo $PATH` which returns:

> /home/myUser/.config/composer/vendor/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

I'm attempting to edit `~/.bashrc`, but I cannot find anything there that says "export PATH". I wanted to try to change it to `export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"` as the Stack Exchange answer suggests.

But perhaps this isn't the right thing to do for Laravel? How can I get Brew to run after installing it?

Comment: It isn't clear from your question what this has to do with Laravel? Regarding your path, a quick search for "Ubuntu path" turns up lots of info, eg https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path

Comment: You have to follow the instructions for this package: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man7/linuxbrew-wrapper.7.html

Comment: @bfontaine, I do not see instructions on that page of what to do specifically. I see a description, but I'm still confused what it could mean.

Comment: I think I got it figured out. I used this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33353618/can-i-use-homebrew-on-ubuntu